# How to get 'null' value instead of default value of field column from C# thrift.dll with hiveserver2

Tags: c#, hive, thrift, thrift-protocol

I'm currently using HiveServer2 with thrift.dll library. If I try to make a tuple from a thrift object, I expect that fields that were not set in the object, are marked null in tuple. However instead default values are put into the tuple. E.g.

```
HqlConnection con = new HqlConnection("localhost", 10001, HiveServer.HiveServer2);    
con.Open();   
HqlCommand createCommand1 = new HqlCommand("select id,name,age,DOB,marks from engineer_list", con);   
createCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();   
HqlDataReader reader = createCommand1.ExecuteReader();
```

expected output should be

> {(1,'John',24,2010-01-01 10:22:47,45.6), (2,null,null,null,null)}

but actual result was:

> {(1,'John',24,2010-01-01 10:22:47,45.6), (2,,,0,0)}

When we send request to call numeric column which contain NULL value for a type (int, double, long, float..) means `thrift.dll` itself return as zero instead of `null` or `DBNull.value`.

For string, timestamp type mean `thrift.dll` itself return as empty string instead of `null` or `DBNull.value`.

By analyzing the source of `thrift.dll`, we trigger out the method for reading the column by following

**Class:** Thrift.Protocol.TBinaryProtocol

**Method:** ReadAll(buffer, offset, length) by default it return as zero.

**Description:** This will get stream of data from thriftServer port

For Int value following method are call and this will return as '0' if data contain 'null'

```
private byte[] i32in = new byte[4];
public override int ReadI32()
{
  ReadAll(i32in, 0, 4);
  return (int)(((i32in[0] & 0xff) << 24) | ((i32in[1] & 0xff) << 16) | ((i32in[2] & 0xff) << 8) | ((i32in[3] & 0xff)));
}
```

Comment: This sounds like it ought to be either posted to [the Thrift developer mailing list](http://thrift.apache.org/mailing) or [filed as a bug report](http://thrift.apache.org/developers) instead of being written up here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is there a question hidden somewhere?

Comment: Hi, Actually my question is how to get 'null' value instead of default value of each datatype from thrift which connecting with hiveserver2?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with Thrift: if you store an empty STRING into Hive, then you will get an empty STRING when selecting the field. If you store explicitly a Null STRING then you will get a Null. **That's the way a proper DBMS should work.**

Unfortunately Oracle and SQL Server have their own silly rules for VARCHAR data type (i.e. in Oracle a Null can appear as an empty string and vice-versa, like a wave/particle in quantum physics; and with SQL Server an empty string is more or less a 1-character-long string with a blank).

If you need application-level handling of empty STRINGs then use a conditional query clause such as `CASE WHEN duh ='' THEN CAST(Null AS STRING) ELSE duh END`

*[Edit]* **Never, ever rely on implicit conversions** from STRING to numeric data types. And I agree that in that case Hive is even worse than other databases.

`CASE WHEN duh is Null OR duh ='' THEN CAST(Null AS SMALLINT) ELSE cast(duh as SMALLINT) END`

PS: casting Nulls is required in some versions of Hive (especially in V0.14 - regression from V0.13)

Answer (score 0):

check the nulls field. e.g. if the nulls[0] = 12. then its binary value is "1100", read from right to left, it means the last two values is acutally NULL value.